# Google Maps map global variable defined in one function, but not in another?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a very simple Google Maps project.

'map' is defined as a global variable.

Function 'initialize' gets information from Google Latitude, creates a map, sets a marker and infowindow, and sets an interval to call function 'update.' It works fine.

Function 'update' is supposed to unset the marker, close the infowindow, get new information from Latitude, set a new marker and infowindow, and pan to the new map center. From the 'undefined' errors its clear that the map variable is not recognized inside the update function.  Since 'map' is a global variable, and the map has already been created, shouldn't I be able to just refer to the variables?

Sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    var map = null;  
    var marker = null;

    function initialize() {

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position:markerlocation,
                map:map,
                visible:true
        });

        setInterval(function(){update()},5000);

    } // end function initialize

    function update() {

        marker.setmap(null);
        infowindow.close:

    // do other stuff

    } // end function update
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When this is the real code the "undefined" thing is the function `setmap`, it should be `setMap`

Comment: I should have noticed that - that's it. Thanks!